# Why is declaring the variables inside a function much slower (too slow for jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, function, variables, jupyter-notebook

I have the following function, it combines multiple functions but this is the "final function"

```
boek = set()
vol_boek = set(np.arange(10))

def tellen():
    aantal_keren = 0
    while boek != vol_boek:
        plakken()
        aantal_keren += 1
    print(f"Er waren {aantal_keren} pakjes nodig om het boek te vullen.")
```

This works fine, "boek" and "vol_boek" are declared outside of "tellen()" It is fast and works well.

however, when i place the declaration of "boek" and "vol_boek" inside of "tellen()" like this it is really slow and jupyter notebook times out after a while. Can you tell me why this is? It seems the same in the essence. Is there a way to execute the function with set() inside? I need to start the function with an empty set, so I used boek = set().

This is my code with the declaration inside:

```
def tellen():
    boek = set()
    vol_boek = set(np.arange(10))
    aantal_keren = 0
    while boek != vol_boek:
        plakken()
        aantal_keren += 1
    print(f"Er waren {aantal_keren} pakjes nodig om het boek te vullen.")
```

p.s. this is the rest of my code:

```
def inhoud_pakje():
    pakje = np.random.choice(range(10), 4, replace=False)
    return pakje
```

```
def plakken():
    pakje = inhoud_pakje()
    for i in pakje:
        boek.update(pakje)
    return boek
```

Comment: Are you sure its not just erroring because `boek` is undefined in `plakken`?

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I have added `boek = set()` to the "top" of the notebook and `boek = set()` to "plakken()" as well. This way i hope to start every execution of plakken with an empty "boek".  This doest not work. The cell in jupyter notebook keeps running for ever.

Comment: I fixed it! using boek.clear() to start with an "empty set" thanks for your answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just getting an error with boek being undefined in plakken, you need to pass it in as a parameter instead.

```
plakken(boek)
```

```
def plakken(boek):
```